# Process of execution for a program on android

Tags: java, android

This is to avoid misconceptions in my mind. Please correct the first one and answer second.

1. As I know for a simple program in java, a compiler compiles the source code to a Byte code which is interpreted by a virtual machine at `run time`. Byte code can be understood only by `JVM` not by native machine. JIT compiler can convert the Bytecode dynamically to native Machine code which can be run by OS as a process. For a program, what is the process of execution and intermediate files on android.? Which language programs can be converted to android native files(.dex..?)?
2. Can JDK be installed on Android.? or atleast JVM.? Is there any android browser which can have Java run time plug in.? I have few applets on my site. I am unable to open them in android. Are there any android version of applets.?
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: Yes. They're great questions, but please split them into separate "questions" on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs are commonly written in a dialect of Java and compiled to bytecode. Then they are converted from Java Virtual Machine-compatible .class files to Dalvik-compatible .dex (Dalvik Executable) files before installation on a device.

Read [Dalvik (software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29)

Answer (score 0):

Check [Dalvik Machine's Web Site](http://www.dalvikvm.com/) and [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) for more info.

Comment: Please don't post answers that are just links. Answers on SO should stand on their own. (There are many reasons for this, and the topic has been discussed extensively on Meta SO if you want to read up on it.)